# Rearranging information in Excel Table using formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have something like this:

[image]

And want to obtain these two columns:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea to do this using only formulas in Excel?

Comment: Unfortunately, don't have access to Excel to test.

Anyway, first step, is to create the data for the first column. The greatest number of possible colours will be no. of rows times no. of columns (in the above case, 9 possible colours). So for the first column, you fill-up 9 cells with formulae, where the first formula finds the first colour sorted alphabetically, the second formula finds the second colour, etc. Does this route sound like a solution that might be acceptable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume "Input Table" housed in A1:D4 and "Output Table" housed in F1:G5

1] "Unique color name" `F2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$4)/1%+{2,3,4}/(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,$B$2:$D$4)=0),1),"R0C00"),0),"")
```

2] "Merged column/row header name" `G2`, array (CSE) formula copied down :

```
=IF(F2="","",TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX($A$1:$D$1,N(IF(1,0+RIGHT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$4)/1%+{2,3,4}/($B$2:$D$4=F2),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF($B$2:$D$4,F2)))),2))))&":"&INDEX($A$1:$A$4,N(IF(1,0+LEFT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$4)/1%+{2,3,4}/($B$2:$D$4=F2),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF($B$2:$D$4,F2)))),1))))))
```

[image]